# Pivot account date list to account start and end dates with missing dates

Tags: t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I have this requirement to convert a list of account active dates to provide the active start and end dates for each sequence of dates and the days between the dates. For example, this is the list of active dates for two accounts.

[image: List of active dates]

And this is the required result set that shows the date sequence start and end and the number of days between those dates.

[image: Results requirement]

However, it's been a puzzle on how to actually do this. Has anyone done this before?

Here's some code with sample data.

```
If Object_Id('dbo.account_active') Is Not Null
```

Drop Table dbo.account_active;

Create Table dbo.account_active(
    account_active_id int Identity(1,1),
    account_id int,
    active_date date);

Insert Into dbo.account_active(
    account_id,
    active_date)
Values
    (1,'2019-01-01'),
    (1,'2019-01-02'),
    (1,'2019-01-03'),
    (1,'2019-01-06'),
    (1,'2019-01-07'),
    (1,'2019-01-08'),
    (1,'2019-01-09'),
    (1,'2019-01-10'),
    (1,'2019-01-11'),
    (1,'2019-01-28'),
    (1,'2019-01-29'),
    (1,'2019-01-30'),
    (1,'2019-01-31'),
    (2,'2019-01-16'),
    (2,'2019-01-25'),
    (2,'2019-01-26');

Select 
    aa.account_id,
    aa.active_date
From 
    dbo.account_active As aa;

Answer (score 3):

This is a **Gaps and Islands** problem

Perhaps this will help.

**Example**

```
Select Account_ID
      ,Active_Date_Start = min(Active_Date)
      ,Active_Date_End   = max(Active_Date)
      ,Days_Active       = DateDiff(DAY,min(Active_Date),max(Active_Date))+1
 From  (
        Select *
              ,Grp = DateDiff(DAY,'1900-01-01',active_date)
                     - Dense_Rank() over (Partition By Account_id Order by Active_Date)
         From  account_active
       ) A
 Group By Account_id,Grp
 Order by Account_id,min(Active_Date)
```

**Returns**

```
Account_ID  Active_Date_Start   Active_Date_End Days_Active
1           2019-01-01          2019-01-03          3
1           2019-01-06          2019-01-11          6
1           2019-01-28          2019-01-31          4
2           2019-01-16          2019-01-16          1
2           2019-01-25          2019-01-26          2
```

Comment: That worked, especially in the older environment where LAG is not available.. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user2466387 Happy to help

Comment: I started testing with a large data set and found the above does not work when there are duplicate active_dates for an account_id. I'll be posting what I found as a solution shortly.

Comment: The requirements are not a count. Just the days between dates. I updated the original post to more accurately reflect this.